# Font Issue? Strange Font behaviour Showing up

Tags: css, html, font-family

I used urdu font but in some pages it works and in some pages it shows in strange language..
I tried to use the font .ttf i also tried to fix my own timezone, but still the problem is showing up..

this is what i am trying to do.
[image]

On this index page the Urdu Font is working Perfectly fine..
http://safijustonline.com/projects/bost/index.html

But on some other pages like this its giving error.
http://safijustonline.com/projects/bost/Admission/admission_policy.html

so why is this problem is showing up??? what is it i have done wrong in these pages?

Comment: do you want the same word to appear on all pages or word changes according to page??

Comment: Try firebug and see console your admission page shows some css missing error

Comment: which font are you using?

Comment: @Usman: "I used urdu font" first paragraph, first words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be a CSS issue. The difference between index.html and admission_policy.html is the character output.

Admission_policy.html:

```
<a id="ctl00_HyperLink15" class="menueshyperlink" href="#">Ù¾Ø´ØªÙˆ</a>
```

index.html:

```
<a id="ctl00_HyperLink15" class="menueshyperlink" href="#">پشتو</a>
```

See the difference? Since your website seems to be static, you could also check your character encoding so it's either utf8 or utf16. You can do this while saving your code.

Comment: Thankyou for Reply, There is someProblem with dreamweaver, i added in urdu and when i safe file and view in browser it shows some strange text, but now when i tried to save it with simple notepad, it is working perfectly fine..
I don't know what is wrong with my dreamweaver. O_o??